# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed in solr import

Tags: mysql, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I encountered an error while doing full-import in solr-6.6.0.
I am getting exception as bellow

This happens when I set
batchSize="-1" in my db-config.xml

If I change this value to say batchSize="100" then import will run without any error.

But recommended value for this is "-1".
Any suggestion why solr throwing this exception.

By the way the data am trying to import is not huge, data am trying to import is just 250 documents.

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:61)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.hasnext(JdbcDataSource.java:464)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.hasNext(JdbcDataSource.java:377)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:133)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:75)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:267)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:516)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:415)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:474)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:457)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

By the way am getting one more warning:

```
Could not read DIH properties from /configs/state/dataimport.properties :class org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException
```

This happens when config directory is not writable.
How can we make config directory writable in solrCloud mode.
Am using zookeeper as watch-dog. Can we go ahead and change permission of config files which are there is zookeeper?
your help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using fetchSize="-1" is only recommended *if you have problems running without it*. Its behaviour is up to the JDBC driver, but the cause of people assuming its recommended [is this sentence from the old wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq):

> DataImportHandler is designed to stream row one-by-one. It passes a fetch size value (default: 500) to Statement#setFetchSize which some drivers do not honor. For MySQL, add batchSize property to dataSource configuration with value -1. This will pass Integer.MIN_VALUE to the driver as the fetch size and keep it from going out of memory for large tables.

Unless you're actually seeing issues with the default values, leave the setting alone and assume your JDBC driver does the correct thing (.. which it might not do with `-1` as the value).

The reason for dataimport.properties having to be writable is that it writes a property for the last time the import ran to the file, so that you can perform delta updates by referencing the time of the last update in your SQL statement.

You'll have to make the directory writable for the client (solr) if you want to use this feature. My guess would be that you can ignore the warning if you're not using delta imports.

Comment: I am running delta-import. How can we make directory writable when we use zookeeper to store these configuration files?